# Android : How to set an image to an imageview from a url programatically

Tags: android, image, url, bitmap, imageview

I have an image url coming from my rest API.  Now I want to set it to an imageview when activity is loading. Below is how I get the bean from the rest api and then get the URL out of it.

```
Message message=new Message();
String imageUrl=message.getImageUrl();
```

I get Message object from my database and image url is include in that Message object.

Then I used Url object to get that image url.

```
URL url = null;
try {
     url = new URL(imageUrl);
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
     contentImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used above codes to load image to an imageview object which is `contentImageView`.

But still I cannot load this image to imageview, Nothing is getting loaded.

have any ideas?

Comment: Change bitmap image to some picture to see if you catch any exception or not by showing the picture in image view.

Comment: You have to load imageview in AsyncTask . After the image is fully downloaded from the url then you can show the image in imageview .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is by using something like Picasso or Glide:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imgUrl).fit().into(contentImageView);
```

you can add picasso library in your gradle: 
`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Comment: Ya , using **Picasso** is awesome but using it with loopers and handlers makes fetching and recycling very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Please Try this function to get `bitmap`

```
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Glide or picasa library for efficient performance

Dependices

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Sample Code

```
  Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(imageview);
```

References:
 Glide official docs https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without any libraries:

1. If you have bitmap image in memory

   setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)   // Sets a Bitmap as the content of this ImageView.
2. If you have image in drawable folder

   setImageResource(int resId)   // Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html